# How to create a Report using ReportViewer?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

i need now to make a `report`. I found some threads here but it just show how to implement some of reportviewer's functions, and I need to know how to `create one` from the beginning... Its really differente than create one on WindowsForm ;\

Any help or tip ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just did it recently. There are a lot of manuals, like this [MSDN Walkthrough: Creating a ReportViewer Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252073%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or this

[Creating an ASP.NET report using Visual Studio 2010 - Part 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/09/creating-an-asp-net-report-using-visual-studio-2010-part-1.aspx)

[Creating an ASP.NET report using Visual Studio 2010 - Part 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/09/creating-a-asp-net-report-using-visual-studio-2010-part-2.aspx)

[Creating an ASP.NET report using Visual Studio 2010 - Part 3](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/09/creating-a-asp-net-interactive-report-using-visual-studio-2010-part-3.aspx)